# Recover Corrupt Audio Data (files visible but not accessible)

Tags: windows, audio, file-corruption, wav

I'm was doing PA and recording at a medical conference this weekend but have hit distaster with corrupt data.

Was recording a .WAV file using a line into a Tascam DR-40 audio recorder. Recorded about 2hrs 40min. Hit stop, and am hit with "File error". Pop the card into my computer. This is what I see.

[image: Corrupt Files from Tascam DR-40]

Problem is, I cannot rename, or access the files. I can see 1.3 GB of data there. But the file names are unintelligible, and when I try to rename or move the files I get:

[image: Item Not Found]

Any ideas out there? I'm missing 2 hrs of important presentations... At my wits end to know what to do here.

Comment: I think unfortunately there's nothing to do.

Comment: sad day.... :(  The data is there somewhere/how though?

Comment: randomly sprayed over the card, by the looks of it. You could try a file scavenger, but i wouldn't hold any high hopes.